# understanding compactness of the support of a function

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I have a doubt proving that if $f,g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ then $f+g \in \mathcal{C}^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$ in particular I would like to know why from this inclusion:
$supp(f+g) \subset supp(f) \cup supp(g)$
 I can conclude that the $supp(f+g)$ is compact? If $supp(f) \cap supp(g) \neq \phi$ then two compact sets with at least one point in common are compact. But what if $supp(f) \cap supp(g)= \phi$ ?

Comment: The union of a finite number of compact sets is still compact. Also, the support of a function is defined to be closed, so since closed subsets of compact sets are compact, $\text{supp}(f+g)$ will also be compact.

Comment: If $f(0)=0$ and $g(0)=0$, then $(f+g)(0)=0$. Therefore, if $x \in \mathbb{R}\setminus(\mbox{supp}(f)\cup\mbox{supp}(g))$, then $(f+g)(0)$. So the support of $f+g$ is contained in the complement of this set, which is $\mbox{supp}(f)\cup\mbox{supp}(g)$.